How to upload file from Deluge to Catalyst Filestore?
I have an creator application where the user uploads their resume for job application. I need to store that application in Catalyst FileStore so can someone share me any code snippet for uploading files using Deluge to Catalyst Filestore?

To upload files from your Deluge function, you need to get the File from your Deluge function and use catalyst filestore uploadFile API to send the files. You can get the necessary and how to upload file using Upload File API in Deluge using the below sample code snippet
//create the headers for the Catalyst API's
headerMap = Map();
headerMap.put("Authorization","Zoho-oauthtoken {access_token}"); // create token with the required scope ZohoCatalyst.files.CREATE
headerMap.put("Environment","Development");

//get file from a source
getFile = invokeurl
[
    url :"https://img.zohostatic.com/catalyst/img/Face_Sample_Image-2-a4fa6f6a69.jpg"
    type :GET
];
info getFile;

// upload the file to the catalyst filestore
filelist = List();
filelist.add({"paramName":"code","content":getFile});
filelist.add({"paramName":"file_name","content":"Face_Sample.jpg","stringPart":"true"});

uploadFile = invokeurl
[
url :"https://api.catalyst.zoho.com/baas/v1/project/{project_id}/folder/{folder_id}/file"
    type :POST
    headers:headerMap
    files:filelist
];
info uploadFile;


return "";

To know more info on Catalyst API you can follow the official help documentation from here.
